# undefined reference to wxLog::DoLog error building wxHaskell against wxWidget 3.0

Tags: c++, haskell, wxwidgets, vtable, wxhaskell

I am trying to build wxHaskell for wxWidgets 3.0. I used the latest git version of wxHaskell from https://github.com/wxHaskell/wxHaskell.

I tried to follow `install.txt` in wxHaskell-master.zip, what I did so far is:

```
cd wxdirect
cabal install
cd ../wxc
cabal install
```

`wxc` won't compile because its Setup.hs requires wxWidgets 2.9. I replaced

```
let wxRequiredVersion = "2.9"
```

with

```
let wxRequiredVersion = "3.0"
```

and then did:

```
cabal install --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/lib
```

All compilation went OK, but I got a few link errors in the end. The hardest one to solve is the following:

```
dist\build\src\cpp\eljlog.o:eljlog.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV6ELJLog[vtable for ELJLog]+0x20): undefined reference to `wxLog::DoLog(unsigned long, char const*, long)'
```

The corresponding source code is in `wxc/src/cpp/eljlog.cpp`:

```
class ELJLog : public wxLog
{
    private:
        TLogFunc func;
        void*    EiffelObject;

    protected:
        virtual void DoLog(wxLogLevel level, const wxChar *szString, time_t t)
                  {
                    wxString s(szString);
                    func (EiffelObject, (int)level, (void*)&s , (int)t);
                  }
              ....
```

I couldn't figure out what caused this error and how to fix it. I did some search about this `vtable` issue, and some suggested that this is caused by declaring a virtual function in a child class without defining it. Others suggested that it's the order that object files are given on the g++ command line. But neither seems to be the case here. 
I tried removing the function `ELJLog::DoLog` function or commenting out the virtual keyword. Strangely, there is always a link error/errors saying something about vtable for ELJLog, and refers to wxLog::DoLog, even when there is no occurrence of DoLog.

Also, as a side note, `wxLog::DoLog` seems to be missing in the wxWidgets 3.0 documentation. I am not sure whether this function is deprecated or not. But still, it's causing errors for legacy derived classes in a way that I can't understand.

Any ideas what's going on here?

--- EDIT2 ---

If I comment out the function in question

```
virtual void DoLog(wxLogLevel level, const wxChar *szString, time_t t) ...
```

I got different link errors as follows:

```
dist\build\src\cpp\eljlog.o:eljlog.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV6ELJLog[vtable for ELJLog]+0x
20): undefined reference to `wxLog::DoLog(unsigned long, char const*, long)'
dist\build\src\cpp\eljlog.o:eljlog.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV6ELJLog[vtable for ELJLog]+0x
24): undefined reference to `wxLog::DoLog(unsigned long, wchar_t const*, long)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

--- EDIT ---

I worked on this under mingw32 from mingw.org. I built wxWidgets 3.0.0 stable release from source, and the stpes I did were as follows:

```
per http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/win32api-version-4-td32288.html :
 edit line 2217 of /c/mingw/{,mingw32/}include/commctrl.h to read
 #define TV_DISPINFO NMTVDISPINFO
 instead of
 #define TV_DISPINFO __AW(NMTVDISPINFO) 
The above was needed to fix a MinGW32 4.8.1-4 issue. Then,

./configure --enable-stl --disable-shared
make
make install

./configure --enable-stl
make
make install 
mv /usr/local/lib/wx*.dll /c/mingw/bin/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a definition for

```
virtual void DoLog(wxLogLevel level, const char *szString, time_t t)
```

is missing in the subclass `ELJLog` of `wxLog`. Adding the following copy of `DoLog` differing in the interface only solved the problem:

```
virtual void DoLog(wxLogLevel level, const char *szString, time_t t)
{
    wxString s(szString);
    func (EiffelObject, (int)level, (void*)&s , (int)t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the compilation error. I am not familiar with wxChar, and don't understand why a duplicate with char *szString should be needed. I personally made two copies of the DoLog function, one with char *szString, and the other with wchar_t *szString. It compiles as well.

Comment: This eventually solve the compilation problem, but I am getting runtime errors about wxc.dll. I am not sure whether it's safe to duplicate definition like this. Should every function in wxWidgets be defined twice one with char and another with wchar_t?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your build steps now, I don't understand why do you build both the static and shared versions of the libraries. Do you really need both of them? Usually just one (typically shared/DLL when building extensions) is enough. If you do need both, you really should build them in different build directories to avoid weird build issues due to having the files from the old build. So I'd advise to do the following:

1. Entirely delete your existing sources.
2. Get them anew (and apply the MinGW fix).
3. Create `build_shared` subdirectory and run `../configure && make && make install` there.
4. If this is not enough, i.e. if you really need the static libraries too, create `build_static` subdirectory of the top level sources directory and run `../configure --disable-shared && make && make install` there.

If anything goes wrong in the future, you can always just do `rm -rf build_whatever` and create a new build directory and rebuild there (`cd build_whatever && make -s clean` works also, but `rm -rf` is more satisfying).

---

Original answer below: it can still be useful to somebody else but it doesn't seem to apply in your case.

---

One possibility is that you built wxWidgets without 2.8 compatibility. It is on by default, so check that you didn't use `--disable-compat28` configure option (I guess this is under Unix?).

If `wxLog::DoLog()` is actually there in the library (you could use `nm` or `objdump` to check this), then I'd check for the use of obsolete g++ `#pragma interface` and `#pragma implementation` pragmas as they can result in such breakage IME. If you do find them anywhere, just remove them completely (but remove both of them, otherwise you are certain to have link errors).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Could you be more specific on the steps? I did this under mingw32. Please see the update.

Comment: I re-built wxWidgets with `--dsiable-compat28`. Now there are much more link errors. The first two are: dist\build\src\cpp\apppath.o:apppath.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[vtab
le for wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0xa0): undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::SetVirtualSizeHints(int, int, int, int)'
dist\build\src\cpp\apppath.o:apppath.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV20wxMDIParentFrameBase[vtable for wxMDIParentFrameBase]+0x110): undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::MakeModal(bool)'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to imply that you ''had'' to use `--disable-compat2.8`, it was just a guess that you might have done it. As you hadn't used it initially, the only problem I can see is that you build both the shared and static versions in the same directory, I'll update the answer to address this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Another potential issue is `wxLog::DoLog()` itself. I remember searching for its documentation, and it has different argument types between 2.8 and 2.9. In 3.0, the function seems to have been removed (reading from the documentation). I had three link errors initially and two others were about `wxLog::OnLog()`. Those went away after commenting them out in the source code. The `DoLog` issue however, is persistent. Even if I comment it out at the problem site, it still reports a link issue.